# Jenkins pass value of Active Choices Parameter

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins job with "Active Choices Parameter" and "Active Choices Reactive Parameter".

```
pipeline {
   agent { label 'Agent_Name' }

   stages {
      stage('Build') {
         steps {
            script {
                def res=build job: 'App_Build', parameters: [string(name: 'ActiveChoicesParam', value: 'Dev'),string(name: 'ActiveChoicesReactiveParam', value: 'Server1')]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I am trying to call the jenkins job and pass parameter values using pipeline script. However, I am getting the following error:

> The parameter 'ActiveChoicesParam' did not have the type expected by
> App_Build. Converting to Active Choices Parameter.
>
> The parameter 'ActiveChoicesReactiveParam' did not have the type expected by
> App_Build. Converting to Active Choices Reactive Parameter.

They (Dev and Server1) are valid values - How can I pass these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting up as new StringParameterValue's

```
build(job: "App_Build",
    parameters: [
        new StringParameterValue('ActiveChoicesParam', 'Dev'),
        new StringParameterValue('ActiveChoicesReactiveParam', 'Server1')
    ],
)
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, it doesn't select the parameter value, it always selects the 1st item in the list. :-(

Answer (score 0):

somehow `new StringParameterValue( 'key', 'value' )` doesn't work for me. I'm using;

```
List<ParameterValue> newParams = [
  [ $class: 'StringParameterValue' , name: 'ActiveChoicesParam'         , value: 'Dev'     ] ,
  [ $class: 'StringParameterValue' , name: 'ActiveChoicesReactiveParam' , value: 'Server1' ] ,
]

def res = build ( job        : 'App_Build' ,
                  propagate  : false       ,
                  wait       : true        ,
                  parameters : newParams
                )
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, it doesn't select the parameter value, it always selects the 1st item in the list.  :-(