# How to pass Extensible Choice parameter type to Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We upgraded our Jenkins plugins, and now our jobs that pass String types to called jobs that have extensible choice parameter are core dumping.

Say I have Job1 calling Job2, and Job2 has an Extensible Choice type parameter called TARGET_VERSION, which is a Groovy script that gets all the successful job numbers of a certain job.

[image]

I used to be able to do this from Job1

```
Job1:
node('someNode') {
  stage('Call Job2') {
    build job: 'Job2',
          parameters: [string(name: 'TARGET_VERSION', value: '1.2')],
          wait: false
  }
}
```

But after the plugin update, I get the following. How can I define the `TARGET_VERSION` as an extensible choice type instead of `string` in Job1?

```
The parameter 'TARGET_VERSION' did not have the type expected by Job2. Converting to Extensible Choice.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal choice '1.2' in parameter 'TARGET_VERSION'
    at jp.ikedam.jenkins.plugins.extensible_choice_parameter.ExtensibleChoiceParameterDefinition.createValueCommon(ExtensibleChoiceParameterDefinition.java:456)
    at jp.ikedam.jenkins.plugins.extensible_choice_parameter.ExtensibleChoiceParameterDefinition.createValue(ExtensibleChoiceParameterDefinition.java:493)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.BuildTriggerStepExecution.completeDefaultParameters(BuildTriggerStepExecution.java:179)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.BuildTriggerStepExecution.start(BuildTriggerStepExecution.java:93)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:286)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:179)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor275.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:160)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:157)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:158)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:162)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:132)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:132)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:3)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:86)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor202.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatch(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:55)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.item(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor205.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:400)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:312)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins pass value of Active Choices Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60305791/jenkins-pass-value-of-active-choices-parameter)

Comment: @zett42, thanks. Though in my case it may be `ExtensibleChoiceParameter` (if it's a valid type) but I'll try both.

Answer (score 1):

@zett42 pointed me in the right direction with [Jenkins pass value of Active Choices Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60305791/jenkins-pass-value-of-active-choices-parameter)

However, since my Job2 is an extensible choice, I had to do this

```
node('someNode') {
    stage('Call Job2') {
        build job: 'Job2',
        parameters: [
            new StringParameterValue('ExtensibleChoiceParam',
                                     'TARGET_VERSION',
                                     '1.2')
        ],
        wait: false
    }
}
```

NOTE: This is NOT the answer! The above code only alleviates the core dump, but it does NOT pass the value from Job1 to Job2.

However, I have a follow up question [How to pass Extensible Choice parameter “value” to Jenkins pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60442259/how-to-pass-extensible-choice-parameter-value-to-jenkins-pipeline)

Comment: Hmmm, however I see 2 bugs. 1) Job2 (which just prints TARGET_VERSION) is NOT showing the value I pass onto it, `1.2` in this case. It actually runs the script and looks at the last build number of Job1 (which is what my extensible choice script does). 2) Even then, the extensible choice script prints out the previous build number of Job1, instead of the current build number.

Answer (score -1):

I have also 2 jobs and one of the parameter(Extensible Choice) has to be passed on from JOB1 to JOB2.

This was the code which worked for me. I have defined this globally that is before the pipeline also starts.

properties([parameters([[$class: 'ExtensibleChoiceParameterDefinition', choiceListProvider: [$class: 'GlobalTextareaChoiceListProvider', addEditedValue: false, name: 'SVN_BRANCH'], description: '', editable: false, name: 'SVN_BRANCH'], extendedChoice(defaultBindings: '', defaultGroovyClasspath: '', defaultGroovyScriptFile: '/var/lib/jenkins/scriptler/scripts/SVN_BUILD_REVISION.groovy', description: '', multiSelectDelimiter: ',', name: 'SVN_BUILD_REVISION', quoteValue: false, saveJSONParameterToFile: false, type: 'PT_TEXTBOX', visibleItemCount: 5)])])