# How to pass Extensible Choice parameter "value" to Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I posted [How to pass Extensible Choice parameter type to Jenkins pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60433455/how-to-pass-extensible-choice-parameter-type-to-jenkins-pipeline) and found an answer, that is, I least I don't get the core dump anymore. However, I have 2 follow up questions.

Again I have 2 jobs, Job1 and Job2. Job1 just triggers Job2. Job2 has an extensible choice parameter called `TARGET_VERSION` which runs a script that shows Job1's successful build numbers. Here's the Groovy script

```
import hudson.model.*

BUILD_JOB_NAME = "Job1"

def getBuildJob() {
    def buildJob = null
    Hudson.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).each {
        if (it.fullName == BUILD_JOB_NAME) {
            buildJob = it
        }
    }
    return buildJob
}

List<String> getAllBuildNumbers(Job job) {
        List<String> buildNumbers = []
        (job.getBuilds()).each {
            def status = it.getBuildStatusSummary().message
            if (status.contains("stable") || status.contains("normal")) {
                buildNumbers.add(it.displayName)
            }
        }
        return buildNumbers
}

Job buildJob = getBuildJob()
List<String> buildNumbers = null
if (buildJob) {
  buildNumbers = getAllBuildNumbers(buildJob)
}
return buildNumbers
```

And Job2 is does nothing except this

```
node('someNode') {
  stage('Print target version') {
     println "$TARGET_VERSION"
   }
}
```

So if Job1 has the following build history

```
Build#       result
--------------------
#4           success
#3           fail
#2           success
#1           fail
```

When I run Job2's `Build with parameters`, I get a `TARGET_VERSION` dropdown list showing

```
#4
#2
```

which are Job1's build numbers that passed.

However, Job1 is a pipeline job, and I trigger Job2 this way

```
    build job: 'Job2',
    parameters: [
        new StringParameterValue('ExtensibleChoiceParam',
                                 'TARGET_VERSION',
                                 '666')
    ],
    wait: false
```

IOW, I want to **force** a value for Job2's `TARGET_VERSION`, `666` in this case (LOL). I have 2 issues.

Issue#1: Job2 does NOT print out `666`

Issue#2: Job2 prints out `#2` instead of `#4`. IOW, it prints out the **previous** successful build, NOT the latest one.

Question #1. How can I pass-in a value from Job1 to Job2 extensible choice parameter?

Question #2: Why is Job#2 printing out the Job1's **previous** successful build, instead of the **latest** one?