# Jenkins Groovy : Pass values(list) to Active Choice Parameter while calling different Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I need to pass the value for Active choice parameter while calling a different Jenkins job from my groovy file and the value is of Array/List type.

I have tried this

```
build job: "myjob", parameters:[choice(name: 'paramName', choices:['a','b','c'])]
```

It is giving error

```
No known implementation of class hudson.model.ParameerValue is using symbol 'choice'
```

[Jenkins pass value of Active Choices Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60305791/jenkins-pass-value-of-active-choices-parameter), here I found some thing to pass active choice parameter value but here they are passing string value only, which is not the my case.

Comment: For clarification: the choice parameter can only have one value at the time, which is of type string. Why you have an list there? Is your goal to pass the possible values from the choice parameter as parameters to the second job?

Comment: @Crash, it is 'Active Choices Parameter' and we can have more then one select in that.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and I was unable to pass these types of parameters to a second job, which uses the same parameter. I doubt it's not possible, since there is no "value" type which can be passed to this plugins parameter class.

So the only option I see here, is just to use a string parameter in the second job. I guess in the second job you already do some parsing of that parameter value, so you won't need to change much:

```
properties([
    parameters([
        [$class: 'ChoiceParameter',
            choiceType: 'PT_MULTI_SELECT',
            filterLength: 1,
            filterable: false,
            name: 'TEST_PARAM',
            script: [
                $class: 'GroovyScript',
                fallbackScript: [
                    classpath: [],
                    sandbox: false,
                    script: 'return ["Check Jenkins ScriptApproval page"]'
                ],
                script: [
                    classpath: [],
                    sandbox: false,
                    script: 'return ["One","Two:selected"]'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ])
])

pipeline {
    agent any
    
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                print params.TEST_PARAM
                
                build job: 'test2', parameters: [
                    string(name: 'TEST_PARAM', value: "${params.TEST_PARAM}")
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then in the second job (Name = test2):

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    parameters {
        string(name: 'TEST_PARAM', defaultValue: '')
    }
    
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // split values, guess you're doing this already
                    // since the value of the parameter is also comma-separted
                    // when you get from "Active choice parameter"
                    def testParamValues = "${params.TEST_PARAM}".split(',')
                    
                    testParamValues.each { testParamValue ->
                        print testParamValue.trim()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to use both, the "Active choice parameter" and that string parameter in your pipeline, you could just check which one has a length > 0 and then work with that value.